# Yii2: How to compare two dates?

Tags: php, yii2

In my form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'check_in')->input('date', ['required' => false])->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'check_out')->input('date', ['required' => false])->label(false); ?>
```

there are two fields `check_in` and `check_out` i need to validate this two fields, `check_out` should not be smaller than `check_in` date how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [compare validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator.html) in your model's `rules` function:

```
['check_in', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'check_out', 'operator' => '<='],
```

This will resolve to `$model->check_in <= $model->check_out`

Comment: This will perform s string validation on two dates not the actual date comparison

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use `compare` validator :

```
// first validate date format
[['check_in', 'check_out'], 'date'],
// then compare attributes
['check_out', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'check_in', 'operator' => '>'],
```

Read more about [`compare` validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#compare).

Answer (score 0):

Comparing date values has been available on Yii2:

```
['checkIn', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'checkIn'],
['checkOut', 'date', 'timestampAttribute' => 'checkOut'],
['checkOut', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'checkIn', 'operator' => '<', 'enableClientValidation' => false],
```

You can research more at the resource linked here [Comparing date value](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#comparing-date-values).